# Running database phpunit tests on local docker image and on bitbucket pipelines with same xml configuration

Tags: symfony, docker, phpunit, symfony4, bitbucket-pipelines

I use docker and bitbucket pipelines and I am running database phpunit tests in the local docker container and in bitbucket pipelines. This works. Within the phpunit.xml.dist I indicate the database url.

In the local docker container this is:
mysql://user:password@**mysql-database**:3306/database

In bitbucket pipeline, however:
mysql://user:password@**localhost**:3306/database

I do not want to change the phpunit.xml.dist every time, so the question is, how could I run both on the same host (I do not care if it is "localhost" oder "mysql-database")? I tried to set the container_name in bitbucket-pipelines.yml, but it doesn't work:

```html
definitions:
  services:
    mysql:
      image: mysql:5.6
      container_name: mysql-database
      environment:
        MYSQL_DATABASE: 'database'
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'root'
        MYSQL_USER: 'user'
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'password'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution: 
a) as "goto" mentioned: don't set the database credentials in the phpunit.xml.dist
b) my .env-file credentials were ignored, so I had to set the environment variables in the bitbucket settings

Answer (score 1):

The host database configuration should be handled by the `config_test.yml` not the `phpunit.xml.dist`.

If you can't define a custom parameters in `config_test.yml` for bitbucket, you can define a new symfony environment (ie: `local_test`) , which have its own `config_local_test.yml`

Comment: I am using symfony 4 and have my configuration in the .env file. If I dont add the database url to phpunit.xml.dist my database test fail.

Answer (score 0):

For any Drupal end users out there, this works:

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - ../vendor/bin/drush si --db-url=mysql://user:password@127.0.0.1/database
          - ../vendor/bin/drush rs 8080 &
          - export SIMPLETEST_DB=mysql://user:password@127.0.0.1/database
          - export SIMPLETEST_BASE_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8080
          - ../vendor/bin/phpunit -c core/phpunit.xml.dist --testsuite=unit
        services:
          - mysql
definitions:
  services:
    mysql:
      image: mysql:5.7
      variables:
        MYSQL_DATABASE: 'database'
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'root'
        MYSQL_USER: 'user'
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'password'
```